# urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 405: Not Allowed

Tags: python, http, urlopen

```
import urllib.request

url = 'http://www.oddsportal.com/ajax-next-games/1/0/1/20130820/'
print(url)
page = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
print(page)
```

Any idea why this script gives an error code "urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 405: Not Allowed" when trying to open the url? Couldn't find anything with Google. The url opens normally with Google Chrome. The script has been working normally for a couple of months until today.

Edit: Thanks to the first comments, I managed to create a script which fixes the problem descibed above. Here's the script with the necessary cookie retrieved with Chrome:

```
import urllib.request
import http.cookiejar

url = 'http://www.oddsportal.com/ajax-next-games/1/0/1/20130820/'

cj = http.cookiejar.CookieJar()
opener = urllib.request.build_opener(urllib.request.HTTPCookieProcessor(cj))
opener.addheaders = [('User-Agent', 'Mozilla/5.0')]
opener.addheaders = [('Cookie', 'D_UID=F1BC6DD9-DF9C-380C-A513-6124F4C86999')]

for cookie in cj:
    print(cookie.name, cookie.value)

print(opener.open(url).read()[:50]) # the full page is very long
```

Removing the cookie header will cause an unwanted web page to be retrieved (displays 'ROBOTS' etc. on the last line of the script). Why doesn't Cookiejar store that cookie automatically?

Edit (2): Apparently that cookie changes regularly, so it has to be retrieved automatically. But how?

Comment: Maybe that page has started altering results based on your user agent?  You could look into adding a user agent header to your request, and see if that fixes it.

Comment: This is not the same as Method Not Allowed. I've received this error from a site that doesn't like bots parsing JSON files. Changing user-agent may fix it. You may also need cookies.

Comment: Thanks a lot to both of you! Changing the user agent stopped the error from occurring. However, the retrieved page wasn't what I was looking for. Adding cookie data to headers solved that.

I found the necessary cookie data using Google Chrome debugging tools. For some reason, http.cookiejar.CookieJar() didn't store those cookies. Any idea why?